# Image not being displayed using webcam in opencv

Tags: c++, opencv, visual-studio-2013, webcam, opencv3.0

I have just started to learn opencv, but now stuck in a program.

I am trying to run a program which just displays the video from the in-built webcam.

```
#include <opencv2\highgui\highgui.hpp>

int main() {
cvNamedWindow("Streaming", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);
CvCapture* capture = cvCreateCameraCapture(0);
IplImage* frame;
while (1) {
    frame = cvQueryFrame(capture);
    if (!frame) break;
    cvShowImage("Streaming", frame);
    char c = cvWaitKey(33);
    if (c == 27) break;
}
cvReleaseCapture(&capture);
cvDestroyWindow("Streaming");
return 0;
}
```

All is working fine no errors being thrown, but when i run the program a new window named Streaming is being opened and my webcam light also switch on (means webcam has started), but inspite of all this no video is being displayed in the new window which opened.

Can any help on this? I am just a beginner in this.

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: On my machine this code works perfectly fine! You have a second camera to test the code? Or another software which uses your webcam, maybe it is broken.

Comment: You might be interested in using the C++ interface, an example can be found [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30024908/unrecognized-or-unsupported-array-type-in-cvgetmat/30028217#30028217).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest migrating from your old `cv` implementation to the newly made methods from `OpenCV 2`.

Take a look at the [VideoCapture](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/highgui/doc/reading_and_writing_images_and_video.html#videocapture-videocapture) class, it has much more intuitive methods. For example, you can use the method `isOpened()` to check if your webcam has been successfully activated.

There's also a nice tutorial over [here](http://opencv-srf.blogspot.com.br/2011/09/capturing-images-videos.html) to help you out with the new methods.